# Установка kivy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Пытаюсь установить пакет kivy через PyPi на python При установке возникает такая ошибка:

```
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
```

И установка вылетает. Что делать? Пробовал ставить на версии python 3.6.1 и 3.8, операционка - Windows 10. Помогите, пожалуйста, не думал что при установке одного фреймворка может возникнуть столько проблем, уже около часа с бубном пляшу

Comment: Попробуй запустить cmd от имени администратора

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так и не разобрался, в чем конкретно была проблема, но нашёл хороший туториал - https://riptutorial.com/ru/kivy и последовательно проделав все шаги оттуда, с радостью обнаружил, что все успешно установилось. Кстати, официальный сайт - https://kivy.org проекта почему-то недоступен из России без vpn.